# Uploading multiple files with the help of multer - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, multer

Hey guys until now i was using multer to upload only a single file which i get in my post data from front end with this function, but now i need to send 2 photos into a post api so how do i configure this function to let it accept 2 photo

```
var webinarStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    // Uploads is the Upload_folder_name
    cb(null, "webinar");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    console.log('fffff',file)
    let ext =
      file.originalname.substring(
        file.originalname.lastIndexOf(".") + 1,
        file.originalname.length
      ) || file.originalname;
    cb(null, "webinar" + "-" + Date.now() + `.${ext}`);
  },
});

var webinarImageUpload = multer({
  storage: webinarStorage,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    // Set the filetypes, it is optional
    var filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png/;
    var mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

    var extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());

    if (mimetype && extname) {
      return cb(null, true);
    }

    cb(
      "Error: File upload only supports the " +
        "following filetypes - " +
        filetypes
    );
  },

  // file is the name of file attribute
}).single("file");
```

On the front end side i am sendinf these files like

```
let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", this.state.file);
    formData.append("logo", this.state.logo);
 fetch("https://************", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    })
```

Comment: `upload.single()` --> `upload.array()` ?

Comment: @JeremyThille thanks mate and one more thing until before adding to db i was doing category.imageLogo = `https://****.com/assets/webinars/${req.file.filename}`; now for the second file should i do category.image = `https://****/assets/webinars/${req.logo.filename}`; ??

Comment: I don't know, what happens if you try it?

Comment: error-  undefined stuck at this and no clue :(

Comment: `upload.array()` is for uploading multiple files to the same field, if you want multiple fields, you can use `.fields()`, When receiving multiple files, you can access the files at `req.files`, that's why `req.file` / `req.logo` is undefined